# Azure App Service Plan Overview shows different CPU usage than Application Insights Live Metrics

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Azure App Service Plan (tier P1V2) that contains a number of App Services.  Each of the App Services is attached to an Application Insights instance.

The App Service Plan Overview shows a CPU usage summary of 100%, but Application Insights Live Metrics shows a very low CPU usage.

Is there an explanation for the values being very different or am I doing something wrong?

Here are images showing what I am seeing.  (*Note that the first is taken over roughly 1 hour and the second one is over 60-seconds, but the figures have been the same throughout the time I have been looking at this.*)

[image: App Service Plan Overview]

[image: Application Insights Live Metrics]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the difference between the two charts:

> What is shown in 'Live Metrics Stream' is the CPU usage of w3wp process, whereas what is shown in App Service Plan level is the total Machine CPU usage.

---

For the 100% CPU usage in Application Insight. You can use **Diagnostics and Solve Problem** to see what going wrong.
[image]
[image]

---

You also can have a look at [this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0eab675d-7be6-4805-8d16-eeb9502bed4d/issues-with-100-cpu-usage-on-app-service-plan) to find out what process is occupying CPU kindly look for `total_cpu_time`/`user_cpu_time`/`privileged_cpu_time`..